# Difference between BPP, IP and AM complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory, interactive-proof-systems

I just can't figure out the difference between these three classes of complexity, does anyone know the difference and can explain it in a simple, direct way without too many definitions involved? Thank you very much!

Comment: For those interested in Proof Assistants, there is a new proposed SE site [ProofAssistants](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants?referrer=Njg4YTJmMjYwOTIxNjdkNGEyMmZkNzE0Y2M4YmFhOTY3OWVmNDUwNWM3ZmFlMjYwYTRiYzZiZWY1ODg5ZjdiMqfBIyhShuHO9QbGuJfVwOYRvfVgPfbJQrn2UOFTeOe-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these classes can be described as consisting of languages accepted by certain Arthur–Merlin games. In these games, Merlin, an unlimited but potentially dishonest party, tries to convince Arthur, a probabilistic Turing machine, that the input $x$ belongs to the language $L$. We ask that if $x \in L$ then some Merlin convinces Arthur with probability at least $2/3$, and if $x \notin L$ then every Merlin convinces Arthur with probability at most $1/3$.

Without any further limitations, we get the class IP (which equals PSPACE). If we only allow a constant number of rounds of interaction, we get the class AM (it is known that without loss of generality, there are only *two* rounds). If we don't allow any interaction (Merlin gets no chance to speak), then we get BPP.

Comment: thanks a lot, but, does this mean that Arthur-Merlin games and IP are equivalent then? Since you said that from those and without any limitation we get IP.. but maybe I misunderstood and they are very just similar but used in different contexts? Sorry, english isn't my native language

Comment: I've just found out that generally AM games use a public coin mechanism, while IP a private one, is that the only difference? I also read that the nature of the coin isn't that influent, does this make IP and AM games equal? If yes, why we distinct them, then?

Comment: AM protocols have two rounds, without loss of generality. IP protocols have polynomially many rounds; the number of rounds could depend on $n$. I suggest ignoring the technical issue of public vs private coins for now.

Comment: Also, for some reason you’re equating AM with whatever can be accepted using unrestricted Arthur-Merlin protocols, but that’s just not how AM is defined.

Comment: Rather, AM is so named because there is an Arthur round followed by a Merlin round, in contrast to MA, in which the order is reversed.

Comment: Thank you so much, I gave you best answer. I think its the language barrier that confuses me a bit sadly. Then, what I was wrong was that AM is defined by having a constant number of rounds of interaction (two in this case, A and then M), while when you talk about Arthur-Merlin games it is intended to be unrestricted from any constant, right?

Comment: Right, general Arthur-Merlin games have an arbitrary number of rounds.